# Finding a domain name in a list of predefined IP Addresses

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns, ip

I am using Node.js to create a custom server that will intercept any IP addresses users go to and return the name of the site. For example if a user is going to `64.233.160.4` my server will see that, compare it to the list it already has and return `Google`.

I was told to use Node.js for this task. I looked up creating a DNS using Node.js and found a link to its [API](http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvecname_domain_callback) and worked off of that. I used tried the example from the Node.js DNS API page;

```
var dns = require('dns');

dns.resolve4('www.google.com', function (err, addresses) {
if (err) throw err;

console.log('addresses: ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));

addresses.forEach(function (a) {
   dns.reverse(a, function (err, domains) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

     console.log('reverse for ' + a + ': ' + JSON.stringify(domains));
    });
  });
});
```

and I got the following result;

```
addresses:     ["74.125.24.99","74.125.24.104","74.125.24.103","74.125.24.147","74.125.24.105","74.125.24.106"]
reverse for 74.125.24.99: ["de-in-f99.1e100.net"]
reverse for 74.125.24.104: ["de-in-f104.1e100.net"]
reverse for 74.125.24.103: ["de-in-f103.1e100.net"]
reverse for 74.125.24.147: ["de-in-f147.1e100.net"]
reverse for 74.125.24.105: ["de-in-f105.1e100.net"]
reverse for 74.125.24.106: ["de-in-f106.1e100.net"]
```

This is no good for me as I need `Google` returned not `de-in-f106.1e100.net`, so hence why I am creating a custom DNS.

What I am trying to achieve;

- Have a known range of IP Addresses `64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255`
- Read an IP address `64.233.160.25`
- Compare it to the predefined list and be able to see it is within the range
- If it within the range, return `Google`

I have been told to do this with Node.js and have been scouring the internet for information on how to do this, but I just seem to be getting more and more confused. I know I am expected to show all of the work I have done, but I am still trying to start.
If anyone can give me help and advice, it would be greatly appreciated.